# bitbucket commits are not sent to other users without their approval

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

Me and my friend are using Bitbucket for storing our project repo.
We both use SourceTree.

Today I've noticed that when I commit changes, he does not see this in his SourceTree although it's shown in the website. (even when he refreshes and whatever).

The only thing that resolves this, is when he approves my commit on website. Only then it'll update in his SourceTree.

I can't seem find a way to solve this. Only found out on the internet that this is an optional feature which I could not find out how to disable.

Thanks for helpers.

Answer (score 1):

> Today I've noticed that when I commit changes, he does not see this in his SourceTree although it's shown in the website.

Git is a distributed version control system.

Your copy of the repository, your friend's copy, and the copy on Bitbucket are all fundamentally separate. It is entirely expected that pushing commits to Bitbucket wouldn't update your friend's local copy.

> The only thing that resolves this, is when he approves my commit on website. Only then it'll update in his SourceTree.

I'm not sure what "when he approves my commit on website" means, but one way or another your friend will have to retrieve commits from Bitbucket before seeing them locally.

Commits can be copied between repositories using the `push`, `fetch` and `pull` commands. If your friend pushes the "Pull" button his local copy should get updated, although there can be conflicts that need to be resolved.

You can learn [more about remotes in Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes). You will probably also want to read about [branching and merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell).